# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $

Tags: json, retrofit2, android, gson

```html
public interface notiIterface {
    @GET("user/get_notifications")
    Call<full_noti_sec> getNotification(@Query("userid") String userid, @Query("session") String session);
}
```

This code is giving me an error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
```

Here is my JSON data:

```html
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "Notifications fetched.",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "69",
      "type": "liked",
      "text": "Sandip Ghosh liked your photo.",
      "for_userid": "56",
      "from_userid": "55",
      "for_image": "54",
      "seen": "0",
      "username": "sandip",
      "firstname": "Sandip",
      "lastname": "Ghosh",
      "imgname": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "64",
      "type": "liked",
      "text": "Sandip Ghosh liked your photo.",
      "for_userid": "56",
      "from_userid": "55",
      "for_image": "54",
      "seen": "0",
      "username": "sandip",
      "firstname": "Sandip",
      "lastname": "Ghosh",
      "imgname": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "63",
      "type": "liked",
      "text": "Sandip Ghosh liked your photo.",
      "for_userid": "56",
      "from_userid": "55",
      "for_image": "54",
      "seen": "0",
      "username": "sandip",
      "firstname": "Sandip",
      "lastname": "Ghosh",
      "imgname": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "62",
      "type": "commented",
      "text": "Sandip Ghosh commented onyour photo.",
      "for_userid": "56",
      "from_userid": "55",
      "for_image": "54",
      "seen": "0",
      "username": "sandip",
      "firstname": "Sandip",
      "lastname": "Ghosh",
      "imgname": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "61",
      "type": "liked",
      "text": "Sandip Ghosh liked your photo.",
      "for_userid": "56",
      "from_userid": "55",
      "for_image": "53",
      "seen": "0",
      "username": "sandip",
      "firstname": "Sandip",
      "lastname": "Ghosh",
      "imgname": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "type": "Follow",
      "text": "Sandip Ghosh started following you",
      "for_userid": "56",
      "from_userid": "55",
      "for_image": "0",
      "seen": "1",
      "username": "sandip",
      "firstname": "Sandip",
      "lastname": "Ghosh",
      "imgname": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried everything but nothing works.I am working on retrofit2 and try every solution available on stackoverflow but nothing works.Please anybody help me i am trying to solve this error from 2 weeks but no result.

Comment: your json is invalid, remove all brackets from keys

Comment: Can you post the code for ``full_noti_sec``. I suspect there's a mismatch between your model and the json response